# SFMC date timezone

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

Can we convert Dataview Sent/Open CST date to UTC timezone without using dateadd funtion. Any other timezone related function?

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [query](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query) tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with [AT TIME ZONE](https://bertwagner.com/posts/at-time-zone-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-time-zones-and-daylight-savings-time/).

Here's an example [from SFSE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/349665/5202):

```sql
SELECT 
  t.mailingState
, v.specificUTCDateTime
, case 
    when t.mailingState = 'AB' then convert(datetime2, v.specificUTCDateTime at time zone 'MOUNTAIN STANDARD TIME')
    when t.mailingState = 'VC' then convert(datetime2, v.specificUTCDateTime at time zone 'PACIFIC STANDARD TIME')
  end adjSendDate
from timezones_canada t
outer apply (
  select
     SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETUTCDate()), MONTH(GETUTCDate()), DAY(GETUTCDate()), 19, 30) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' specificUTCDateTime
) v
```